# Is it possible to launch an instance of Chrome/Chromium which is isolated from the rest of the system?

Tags: google-chrome, valgrind

I'm trying to debug some of Chrome's behaviour when running one of my extensions. However the test is fairly memory intensive and I want to run it under Valgrind. Is it possible to launch an instance of the browser which is entirely independent of the rest of by browser windows so I can debug it without having to switch my main browser to something else for the duration?

Comment: Chrome uses a seperate process for each tab to begin with.  You just need to identify which process your dealing with.

Comment: @Ramhound yeah but to use a tool like Valgrind I need to launch it within the Valgrind VM, you can't attach it to an already running process. There are also many additional processes involved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try starting with a different user profile via e.g. the `--user-data-dir=~/profilepath` switch on *nix, or `--profile-directory="profilename"` on Windows. This should start a separate process.